# How to use @ConfigurationProperties for list-valued or array-valued mapping?

Tags: spring-boot

I've got a project where I'd like to configure String-keyed "groups"
of String-keyed "commands" of arrays of Strings. That is, I'd like to
be able to express something like the following in the config.yml, and
consume via @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config.base"):

```
---
config:
  base:
    "bin group":
    - "Directory Listing": ["/bin/ls", "-la"]
    - "Server Date/Time": ["/bin/date", "-u"]
    "usr/bin group":
    - "Find .txt Files": ["/usr/bin/find", ".", "-name", "*.txt"]
    "usr/local/bin group":
    - "Tree Listing": ["/usr/local/bin/tree"]
```

Ideally, I'd want the @ConfigurationProperties object to be a `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>>`

but I can't figure out how to do that. Or anything reasonably close to that.
The closest I've gotten is like the following:

```java
package us.w7tek.bug;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("someConfig")
    @Bean
    public ExternalizedConfig externalizedConfig() { return new ExternalizedConfig(); }

    public static class ExternalizedConfig extends LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> {
        // oops, @ConfigurationProperties ends up putting LinkedHashMap<String, String> in the values of the top-level mapping,
        // and that second-level LinkedHashMap has keys that could have come from Integer#toString
    }

    @Controller
    public static class ControllerThatConsumesConfig {
        private static final String A_KEY_THAT_COULDNT_BE_A_PROPERTY_NAME = "this == config cannot be expressed as a bean with properties, because the keys cannot be made into Java language identifiers for bean property setters and getters";

        @Autowired
        ExternalizedConfig config;

        @PostConstruct
        void init() {
            String[] strings = config.get(A_KEY_THAT_COULDNT_BE_A_PROPERTY_NAME);  //  ClassCastException occurs here

            // doesn't have to occur in @PostConstruct, that was just a convenient place for my demo.
        }
    }
}
```

with the following example `application.yml` in the project:

```
---
someConfig:
    "this is a key": ["this", "value", "is", "not", "an", "String[]"]
    "this is another key": ["it", "is", "deserialized", "as", "LinkedHashMap", "having", "keys", "like", "\"0\"", "and", "\"1\"", "etc."]
    "this == config cannot be expressed as a bean with properties, because the keys cannot be made into Java language identifiers for bean property setters and getters": ["thereby", "subverting", "Java's", "static", "typing", "and", "resulting", "in", "ClassCastException", "at", "runtime"]
```

As indicated in the comment, that code explodes when the Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` binder creates an object of type `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>` and places it in the `config` field. Of course, as soon as any method accesses `config` according to its statically-declared type, a `ClassCastException` occurs. I'm not sure whether to believe this is a bug with the property binder code used by `@ConfigurationProperties`, or just my gross misunderstanding. I think that the above code is the simplest possible thing that exhibits the problem. Also found at https://github.com/w7tek/demo-configproperties-bug.git, in case anyone wants to compile and run to see the stack trace.

Does anyone have any examples of `@ConfigurationProperties` with collections? I can see the way forward from where I'm at, by simply matching the declared type to the actual type Spring has deserialized, but that ends up being significantly less convenient to use. I'd really like to get the innermost values of this config as List<> or array type, if possible, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you needed:

don't use tab, use 2 space for each inner element.

```
config:
  base:
    "bin group":
      "Directory Listing": ["/bin/ls", "-la"]
      "Server Date/Time": ["/bin/date", "-u"]
    "usr/bin group":
      "Find txt Files": ["/usr/bin/find", ".", "-name", "*.txt"]
    "usr/local/bin group":
      "Tree Listing": ["/usr/local/bin/tree"]
```

and here is the Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix  = "config")
public class Conf_Test {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>> base;

    public LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>> getBase() {
    return base;
    }

    public void setBase(LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>> base) {
    this.base = base;
    }

}
```

Apperantly, you cannot use "." inside the map key, it just cut the key so I removed the one in "Find .txt Files" key. Also, spring-boot doesn't support auto-groving arrays inside map, so String[] is not possible for now but list is working.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, but thanks for trying.
When running your solution, the actual type of the thing that gets passed in to setBase is not the same as the declared type: it is another example of the same problem. I think the problem could be stated as, "Spring's property accessors can't see past type erasure". The List<String> gets passed in as LinkedHashMap<String, String> with keys like "0", "1", "2", etc. In other words, the same problem.

Comment: If the key contains a dot, you must use the bracket notation, i.e. `foo.items[two.bar]=2` will set the `two.bar` key. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding

Comment: This answer produces what you're asking for: `bin group={Directory Listing=[/bin/ls, -la], Server Date/Time=[/bin/date, -u]}, usr/bin group={Find .txt Files=[/usr/bin/find, ., -name, *.txt]}, usr/local/bin group={Tree Listing=[/usr/local/bin/tree]}}`. Note that the yaml file changed as you had "Directory Listing" and others as a list ('-') instead of a map.